# Depends on both cloud_firestore 0.14.4 and http 0.13.3, version solving failed

Tags: http, google-cloud-firestore, version

Depends on both cloud_firestore 0.14.4 and http 0.13.3, version solving failed.

flutter pub get
Warning: You are using these overridden dependencies:
! http 0.12.2 (0.13.3 available)
! intl 0.17.0
Running "flutter pub get" in customer...                         2,032ms

flutter pub get
Because cloud_firestore_web 0.2.1+2 depends on http_parser ^3.1.3 and no versions of cloud_firestore_web match >0.2.1+2 <0.3.0, cloud_firestore_web ^0.2.1+2 requires http_parser ^3.1.3.
And because http >=0.13.0 depends on http_parser ^4.0.0 and cloud_firestore 0.14.4 depends on cloud_firestore_web ^0.2.1+2, http >=0.13.0 is incompatible with cloud_firestore 0.14.4.
So, because dailysauda depends on both cloud_firestore 0.14.4 and http 0.13.3, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in customer...
pub get failed (1; So, because dailysauda depends on both cloud_firestore 0.14.4 and http 0.13.3, version solving failed.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the latest versions of the packages.

As of this reply, the latest versions are:

```
cloud_firestore: ^2.2.2
http: ^0.13.3
```

This should solve your issue.

Reason behind it is likely the differences in the packages with newer features such as nullable checks etc.

Comment: Getting now   Because firebase_auth 0.18.4+1 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^2.1.0 and cloud_firestore >=2.1.0 depends on firebase_core_platform_interface ^4.0.1, firebase_auth 0.18.4+1 is incompatible with cloud_firestore >=2.1.0.
So, because dailysauda depends on both cloud_firestore ^2.2.2 and firebase_auth 0.18.4+1, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in customer...
pub get failed (1; So, because dailysauda depends on both cloud_firestore ^2.2.2 and firebase_auth 0.18.4+1, version solving failed.)

Comment: Please share contents of your pubspec.yaml file